# Adobe flash Youtube Video

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube, banner

How would i emded a youtube video into a Flash banner, Without the controlls, just a play and pause button on the video and A link to youtube, (it going to be very small.

This i what it needs to look like:

[image: Screenshot of what i want]
[image: Screenshot of what i want]]

I am using this code now, but i cant se the video due to the bar at the bottom:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

var my_player:Object;
var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/wQ-UltJAjMU?version=2"));

//http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfU5Hj3uKZ4
//btn_go
btn_go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLoaderInit);

function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void{
btn_go.visible=false;
addChild(my_loader);
my_player = my_loader.content;
my_player.setSize(106,56);
my_player.addEventListener("onReady");
}
```

This is what my code makes me: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the chromeless player (http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3). [Instructions here.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#GettingStarted)

When it's loaded, tell it to play the video you need using `player.loadVideoById("wQ-UltJAjMU")`. ([API reference.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Queueing_Functions))

Edit: or `player.cueVideoById("wQ-UltJAjMU")` if you need it to load and display the video thumbnail but not start playing automatically.